# How can I implement fading in and out of Added/Removed ListItems

Tags: wpf, animation, listbox

Suppose I have a `ListBox` bound to an `ObservableCollection` and I want to animate adding/removing of `ListBoxItems` eg. FadeIn/Out, SlideDown/Up etc. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dr TJ's answer is right enough.  Going down that route you'd have to wrap `ObservableCollection<T>` and implement a BeforeDelete event,..then you could use an `EventTrigger` to control the storyboards.

That's a right pain though. You're probably better creating a `DataTemplate` and handling the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` and `FrameworkElement.Unloaded` events in an `EventTrigger`.

I've put a quick sample together for you below.  You'd have to sort out the remove code yourself but I'm sure you're up to it.

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="sys:String">
                <sys:String>One</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Four</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Five</sys:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                           Opacity="0">
                    <TextBlock.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="00:00:02"
                                                     From="0"
                                                     To="1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Unloaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="00:00:02"
                                                     From="1"
                                                     To="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </TextBlock.Triggers>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

HTH, Stimul8d

Comment: I was looking for a solution like this for the LongListSelector on Windows Phone, but alas I found this comment on the MSDN documentation page for the FrameworkElement.Triggers property "EventTrigger can only support a triggering action for the Loaded event (you name the triggering event in the EventTrigger.RoutedEvent property.)"   
Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the animation that's fired on the `FrameworkElement.Unloaded` event will never be visible, since the item is removed from the view immediately.

Comment: Same remark here, the event is fired after the item is made not visible anymore.

Answer (score 36):

After spending mad hours hunting the wilds of Google, I figure I should share how I solved this problem since it seems to be a pretty d*mn simple thing to need and yet WPF makes it ridiculously frustrating until you intimately understand how animation is implemented. Once you do, you realize FrameworkElement.Unloaded is a useless event for animation. I've seen many versions of this question all over StackOverflow (amongst others), with all sorts of hackish ways to solve this. Hopefully I can provide a most simple example that you can then fancy up for your many purposes.

I will not show Fade In example since that is covered by plenty of examples using the Loaded routed event already. It is Fading Out on item removal that is the royal pain in the *@$.

The major problem here stems from how Storyboards just get weird when you put them into Control/Data Templates / Styles. It is impossible to bind the DataContext (and thus your object's ID) to the Storyboard. The Completed event fires with zero idea of who it just finished on. Diving the visual tree is useless since all your data templated items have the same names for their containers! So sure, you could write up a function that goes and searches the entire collection for objects that have their removal flag property set, but that is ugly and honestly, just not something you ever want to admit writing on purpose. And it won't work if you have several objects being removed within the length of your animation of each other (which is my case). You could also just write a cleanup thread that does similar things and get lost in timing hell. No fun. I digress. On to the solution.

Assumptions:

1. You are using ObservableCollection populated with some custom objects
2. You use a DataTemplate to give these a custom look, hence why you want to animate their removal
3. You bind the ObservableCollection to a ListBox (or something simple like it)
4. You have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented on the class of objects in your OC.

Then the solution is quite simple really, painfully so if you spent any long amount of time trying to solve this.

1. Create a Storyboard that animates your fade out in the Window.Resources section of your window (above the DataTemplate).
2. (Optional) Define the Duration separately as a resource so you can avoid hard coding as much. Or just hard code the durations.
3. Make a public boolean property in your object class called "Removing", "isRemoving", whatev. Make sure you raise a Property Changed event for this field.
4. Create a DataTrigger that binds to your "Removing" property and on True plays the fade out storyboard.
5. Create a private DispatcherTimer object in your object class and implement a simple timer that has the same duration as your fade out animation and removes your object from the list in its tick handler.

Code example is below, which hopefully makes it all easy to grasp. I simplified the example as much as possible so you'll need to adapt it to your environment as it suits you.

Code Behinds

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Missiles> MissileRack = new ObservableCollection<Missiles>(); // because who doesn't love missiles? 
    public static Duration FadeDuration; 

    // main window constructor
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // somewhere here you'll want to tie the XAML Duration to your code-behind, or if you like ugly messes you can just skip this step and hard code away 
        FadeDuration = (Duration)this.Resources["cnvFadeDuration"];
        // 
        // blah blah
        // 
    }

    public void somethread_ShootsMissiles()
    {
        // imagine this is running on your background worker threads (or something like it)
        // however you want to flip the Removing flag on specific objects, once you do, it will fade out nicely
        var missilesToShoot = MissileRack.Where(p => (complicated LINQ search routine).ToList();
        foreach (var missile in missilesToShoot)
        {
            // fire!
            missile.Removing = true;
        }
    }
}

public class Missiles
{
    public Missiles()
    {}

    public bool Removing
    {
        get { return _removing; }
        set
        {
            _removing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Removing"); // assume you know how to implement this

            // start timer to remove missile from the rack
            start_removal_timer();
        }
    }
    private bool _removing = false;

    private DispatcherTimer remove_timer;
    private void start_removal_timer()
    {
        remove_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        // because we set the Interval of the timer to the same length as the animation, we know the animation will finish running before remove is called. Perfect. 
        remove_timer.Interval = MainWindow.TrackFadeDuration.TimeSpan; // I'm sure you can find a better way to share if you don't like global statics, but I am lazy
        remove_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(remove_timer_Elapsed);
        remove_timer.Start();
    }

    // use of DispatcherTimer ensures this handler runs on the GUI thread for us
    // this handler is now effectively the "Storyboard Completed" event
    private void remove_timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this is the only operation that matters for this example, feel free to fancy this line up on your own
        MainWindow.MissileRack.Remove(this); // normally this would cause your object to just *poof* before animation has played, but thanks to timer, 
    }

}
```

XAMLs

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Duration x:Key="cnvFadeDuration">0:0:0.3</Duration> <!-- or hard code this if you really must -->
        <Storyboard x:Key="cnvFadeOut" >
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="cnvMissile"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                      From="1" To="0" Duration="{StaticResource cnvFadeDuration}"
                                      />
        </Storyboard>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MissileTemplate">
            <Canvas x:Name="cnvMissile">
                <!-- bunch of pretty missile graphics go here -->
            </Canvas>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Removing}" Value="true" >
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <!-- you could actually just plop the storyboard right here instead of calling it as a resource, whatever suits your needs really -->
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource cnvFadeOut}"  /> 
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox /> <!-- do your typical data binding and junk -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Huzzah!~

Comment: I tried this approach, but I don't get the animation to work. When I set "Removing" to "true", my element disappears after the animation duration but I don't see the animation itself. I also think I correctly have OnPropertyChanged implemented. (sorry I am just a beginner in WPF)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I used another storyboard for the add-animation so I just had to give my first storyboard a name and insert <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="EntryAnimation" /> before I add  my second storyboard.

Comment: This approach is good, but it looks like it is quite dirty. I mean that in your case Missle class is the Model (not even a ViewModel) and it implements a piece of the View logic. As for me, if you want to apply it, don't hardcode "MainWindow" ref into the Model (=Missle) code, but create an event and subscribe to the event in the ViewModel (the class where you host the OblservableCollection). In the short example above View = ViewModel, so MainWindow should subscribe to the event.

Comment: Yup, it is very quick and dirty...was just to illustrate that animated removal is quite possible where back in 2012 / 2013 everything I read told me it was "impossible".  Surprised people are still reading my post from nigh 6 years ago :D  hope it was helpful! I haven't written WPF code in almost 5 years... hah.

Answer (score 2):

Fade-out is likely to be impossible without re-writing the `ItemsControl` base implementation. The problem is that when the `ItemsControl` receives the `INotifyCollectionChanged` event from the collection it immediately (and within deep private code) marks the item container as not visible (`IsVisible` is a readonly property that gets its value from a hidden cache so cannot be accessed).

You can easily implement the fade-in in this way:

```
public class FadingListBox : ListBox
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(
        DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        var lb = (ListBoxItem)element;
        DoubleAnimation anm = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, 
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        lb.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, anm);
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

But the 'fade-out' equivalent never works as the container is already invisible and cannot be reset.

```
public class FadingListBox : ListBox
{
    protected override void ClearContainerForItemOverride(
        DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        var lb = (ListBoxItem) element;
        lb.BringIntoView();
        DoubleAnimation anm = new DoubleAnimation(
            1, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        lb.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, anm);
        base.ClearContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

Even if you have your own custom container generator, you cannot overcome this issue

```
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new FadingListBoxItem();
    }
```

And this kind of makes sense, because if the container was still visible after the data it represents has disappeared, then you could theoretically click on the container (kicking off triggers, events etc) and experience some subtle bugs perhaps.

Comment: Oh seems like like most people said on this post, there is no way on implementing fade-out? I haven't tried your fade-out code, you seem to say that it doesn't work? I guess Sliding will be even tougher? lol. With HTML/CSS/JS such things seem to work really easily esp. with jQeury + plugins etc

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works for animating the addition of new items, but not for the removal of existing ones. This is because by the time the `Unloaded` event fires, the item has already been removed. The key to getting deletion to work is to add a "marked for deletion" concept. Being marked for deletion should trigger the animation, and the completion of the animation should trigger the actual deletion. There are probably a bunch of ways this idea could be implemented, but I got it to work by creating an attached behavior and by tweaking my viewmodels a bit. The behavior exposes three attached properties, all of which must be set on each `ListViewItem`:

1. "Storyboard" of type `Storyboard`. This is the actual animation you want to run when an item is removed.
2. "PerformRemoval" of type `ICommand`. This is a command that will be executed when the animation is done running. It should execute code to actually remove the element from the databound collection.
3. "IsMarkedForRemoval" of type `bool`. Set this to true when you decide to remove an item from the list (e.g. in a button click handler). As soon as the attached behavior sees this property change to true, it will begin the animation. And when the animation's `Completed` event fires, it will `Execute` the `PerformRemoval` command.

[Here](http://streamingcon.blogspot.com/2015/07/wpf-animate-removal-of-listitem-from.html) is a link to full source for the behavior and example usage (if it's bad form to direct to your own blog, I'll remove the link. I'd paste the code here, but it's fairly lengthy. I don't receive any money from the thing, if that makes a difference).

Answer (score 0):

For me `FrameworkElement.Unloaded` event doesn't work - the item just disappears instantly. I can hardly believe that years of experience with WPF haven't produced anything prettier, but looks like the only way this can work is a hack described here: [Animating removed item in Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791247/animating-removed-item-in-listbox) ?..

Answer (score 0):

Heh. Since accepted solution is not work, let's try another round ;)

We can't use Unloaded event because ListBox (or other control) remove item from visual tree when it removed from original list. So main idea is to create shadow copy of provided ObservableCollection and bind list to it.

First of all - XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ShadowView}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Loaded="OnItemViewLoaded">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Create ListBox, bind it to our shadow copy, set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem for correct support ICollectionView.CurrentItem (very useful interface), and set Loaded event on item view. This event handler need to associate view (which will be animated) and item (which will be removed).

```
private void OnItemViewLoaded (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fe = (FrameworkElement) sender ;
    var dc = (DependencyObject) fe.DataContext ;

    dc.SetValue (ShadowViewSource.ViewProperty, fe) ;
}
```

Initialize everything:

```
private readonly ShadowViewSource m_shadow ;

public ICollectionView ShadowView => m_shadow.View ;

public MainWindow ()
{
    m_collection = new ObservableCollection<...> () ;

    m_view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView (m_collection) ;
    m_shadow = new ShadowViewSource (m_view) ;

    InitializeComponent ();
}
```

And last, but not least, ShadowViewSource class (yeah, it's not perfect, but as proof-of-concept it works):

```
using System ;
using System.Collections.Generic ;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel ;
using System.Collections.Specialized ;
using System.ComponentModel ;
using System.Linq ;
using System.Windows ;
using System.Windows.Data ;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation ;

namespace ShadowView
{
    public class ShadowViewSource
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached ("View", typeof (FrameworkElement), typeof (ShadowViewSource)) ;

        private readonly ICollectionView m_sourceView ;
        private readonly IEnumerable<object> m_source ;

        private readonly ICollectionView m_view ;
        private readonly ObservableCollection<object> m_collection ;

        public ShadowViewSource (ICollectionView view)
        {
            var sourceChanged = view.SourceCollection as INotifyCollectionChanged ;
            if (sourceChanged == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (sourceChanged)) ;

            var sortChanged = view.SortDescriptions as INotifyCollectionChanged ;
            if (sortChanged == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (sortChanged)) ;

            m_source = view.SourceCollection as IEnumerable<object> ;
            if (m_source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (m_source)) ;

            m_sourceView = view ;

            m_collection = new ObservableCollection<object> (m_source) ;
            m_view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView (m_collection) ;
            m_view.MoveCurrentTo (m_sourceView.CurrentItem) ;

            m_sourceView.CurrentChanged += OnSourceCurrentChanged ;
            m_view.CurrentChanged += OnViewCurrentChanged ;

            sourceChanged.CollectionChanged += OnSourceCollectionChanged ;
            sortChanged.CollectionChanged += OnSortChanged ;
        }

        private void OnSortChanged (object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (m_view.DeferRefresh ())
            {
                var sd = m_view.SortDescriptions ;
                sd.Clear () ;
                foreach (var desc in m_sourceView.SortDescriptions)
                    sd.Add (desc) ;
            }
        }

        private void OnSourceCollectionChanged (object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var toAdd    = m_source.Except (m_collection) ;
            var toRemove = m_collection.Except (m_source) ;

            foreach (var obj in toAdd)
                m_collection.Add (obj) ;

            foreach (DependencyObject obj in toRemove)
            {
                var view = (FrameworkElement) obj.GetValue (ViewProperty) ;

                var begintime = 1 ;
                var sb = new Storyboard { BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds (begintime) } ;
                sb.Completed += (s, ea) => m_collection.Remove (obj) ;

                var fade = new DoubleAnimation (1, 0, new Duration (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds (500))) ;
                Storyboard.SetTarget (fade, view) ;
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty (fade, new PropertyPath (UIElement.OpacityProperty)) ;
                sb.Children.Add (fade) ;

                var size = new DoubleAnimation (view.ActualHeight, 0, new Duration (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds (250))) ;
                Storyboard.SetTarget (size, view) ;
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty (size, new PropertyPath (FrameworkElement.HeightProperty)) ;
                sb.Children.Add (size) ;
                size.BeginTime = fade.Duration.TimeSpan ;

                sb.Begin () ;
            }
        }

        private void OnViewCurrentChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_sourceView.MoveCurrentTo (m_view.CurrentItem) ;
        }

        private void OnSourceCurrentChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_view.MoveCurrentTo (m_sourceView.CurrentItem) ;
        }

        public ICollectionView View => m_view ;
    }
}
```

And final words. First of all it works. Next - this approach don't require any changes in existing code, workarounds via Deleting property, etc, etc, etc. Especially when implemented as single custom control. You have ObservableCollection, add items, remove, do whatever you want, UI will always try to correctly reflect this changes.

Answer (score -1):

Create two story boards for fade-in and fade-out and bind its value to the brush you've created for the `OpacityMask` of your `ListBox`

Comment: But how do you go about fade out? When the item is deleted from the Collection in the Model the ListBoxItem is instantly deleted. How do you fade it out?

Comment: I think you have to write an `event` like `BeforeDelete` in your model and before deleting an Item from your model, first fire this event and by the way, you know when you should start Fad-out storyboard