# FluidMoveBehavior with ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, blend

I'm trying to get FluidMoveBehavior to work, but nothing is animating no matter what I try.  It just adds/removes items as normal without any fading/sliding in/out. Other examples I downloaded off the internet work just fine and it seems simple to hookup. What am I doing wrong with the code below?

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:SampleData="clr-namespace:Expression.Blend.SampleData.SampleDataSource"           
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Window.Resources>      
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Background="{Binding MyColor}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>              
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
            <StackPanel>
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <ei:FluidMoveBehavior Duration="0:0:5" AppliesTo="Children">
                        <ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                        <ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                    </ei:FluidMoveBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>  
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbTest" Margin="8,47,8,8" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" />
        <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="8,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Click="OnAdd"/>
        <Button Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="112,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Click="OnRemove"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MyItem> items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
        private static Random seed; 

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            seed = new Random();

            lbTest.ItemsSource = items;
        }

        private Color GetRandomColor() 
        { 
            Color newColor = new Color(); 

            newColor.A = (byte)255; 
            newColor.R = (byte)seed.Next(0, 256); 
            newColor.G = (byte)seed.Next(0, 256); 
            newColor.B = (byte)seed.Next(0, 256); 

            return newColor;
        }

        private void OnRemove(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (items.Count > 0)
                items.RemoveAt(items.Count - 1);
        }

        private void OnAdd(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            items.Add(new MyItem() { 
                Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                MyColor = new SolidColorBrush(GetRandomColor())
            });
        }
    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Brush MyColor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Finally figured it out -- needed to add/remove at the head of the list for some weird reason via Insert(0, item) and RemoveAt(0) instead of just Add()/Remove at the end of the list.

Comment: If you want to animate add/remove listbox items, it's probably not the right way to do. This behavior is just to smoothly move items, if you want to control how the item appears and disappears, you might wanna take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171829/how-can-i-implement-fading-in-and-out-of-added-removed-listitems or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637844/animate-wpf-datatemplate-when-item-added-to-listbox

Comment: Thanks @Xin I'll take a look at those links!