# Remove ObservableCollection item with an animation

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard, observablecollection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I implement fading in and out of Added/Removed ListItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171829/how-can-i-implement-fading-in-and-out-of-added-removed-listitems)

I tried `LayoutStates` and `FrameworkElement.Unloaded` to do an animation when I remove my item, but it doesn't work.

I think the item is removed before executing the animation!

Does anyone know a solution?

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Unloaded">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.6"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="1.6"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.6"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="1.6"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```