# How to animate Adding & Removal in ListView/Box?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, wpf-animation

I am trying to understand how **animation** works in **WPF** with **StoryBoards**.

So far I have managed the following :

- creating a ListView with custom items and resources binding ;
- using `ItemContainerStyle` in order to make sure each item takes all the width of the ListView ;
- using `EventTrigger` to trigger specific animation

My problem is simple.

First I tried the `Loaded` trigger to animate an item whenever it is added to the ListView's binded `ObservableCollection`. It works fine with `opacity`property but the problem is that this event is triggered everytime I scroll, meaning Windows loads and unloads items on-the-go to save up memory (which is understable but uses a lot more CPU with complex item).

So it's a no go.
Furthermore, the `Unloaded` trigger "does not really work" and was solved here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14619637/3535408

So, using the aforementioned solution, I would like to fire the animation manually.

To be more precise, whenever a specific property of my items (much like `Removing`) is changed, I'd like a `StoryBoard` to be started.

How to accomplish this for sliding animation ? Because I would really like to have my items to slide, on the X axis, in and out (entering via the left, and leaving via the left) of my ListView.

These sliding animations must be triggered only when an item is **added** to the binded `ObservableCollection` and when it is **removed**.

The following XAML code does not work :

Within a ListView > ListView.ItemTemplate > DataTemplate > DataTemplate.Triggers

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Removing}" Value="true" >
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY" From="0" Duration="0:0:.2"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

The opacity animation really works just fine. However the `LayoutTransform` produces the following **System.InvalidOperationException** : `Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'LayoutTransform.ScaleY'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.`

Moreover, I just do not know how to do a sliding animation on the X axis :/

Here is the content of my ListView's`ItemContainerStyle` :

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, -2, 0, -2" ></Setter>
<Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="transform" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="RenderTransform">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ScaleTransform/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Change `Storyboard.TargetProperty` to something like `"LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"` and it may work. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx) you can read more about paths.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it does not work, the same Invalide Operation Exception occurs. But does it mean the `DoubleAnimation` does not find the `LayoutTransform` property ? So how come it can finds the 'Opacity` property since I never stated it anywhere in my XAML code ? Hm, strange !